# Can't delete folder : 'The path is too long' error

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, windows-8, ms-dos

I'm trying to delete an entire folder in an external drive with the *rd* command, but i'm receiving the error below :

> The path
>   E:\2017_11_10\WWW201~1\myproject\NODE_M~1\GRUNT-~4\NODE_M~1\imagemin\NOD
>   1\BIN-WR~1\NODE_M~1\download\NODE_M~1\GULP-D~1\NODE_M~1\GULP-U~1\NODE_M~1\MULTIP
>   ODE_M~1\STRING~1\PACKAG~1.JSO is too long.

Is there a way to remove this folder without having to format the external hd ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. Get Unlocker 1.92 (Majorgeeks) and use that. You can try the whole folder, but you may need to delete troublesome files individually. Delete all the files you can first. I use this myself.

Comment: You may also need to shorten the path length by renaming top level folders to shorter folder names

Comment: FYI, the official site for Unlocker is [here](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/).